# Soft Question: careless errors as a result of shaky foundation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I nearly failed calculus II and had to drop linear algebra because of mounting basic math errors. I'm going back to school and with a fairly math heavy module and I'm concerned.

On long questions, I felt like I was running out of RAM with each additional step. Most of my mistakes came at the end of the question where I'd make an addition / subtraction / multiplication / division error. It felt like was getting lost in calculations.

Because of this, I'm usually concerned about whether I had made a mistake in prior steps, and keeping this in mind is quite taxing.

Is this because of a shaky foundation, lack of practice, or something else? Are there any extracurricular methods I should be employing?

Comment: Practice with algebra manipulation; solve complicated equation, simplify long expressions, perform long integrals by parts (which get messy pretty fast), etc. Another tip is to write as fast as possible while still making the steps understandable, so that if you mess up a minus sign you can quickly trace back your steps and fix it

Comment: You could also try to get in the habit of doing frequent "sanity checks" after each step of the problem (e.g. check the signs, bounds of the integral, etc.) If you feel you are getting lost in problems you could write  quick outlines of your solutions before writing it out in full (e.g. first I need to substitute u=1/x, then I need need to differentiate... and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Careless mistakes in basic arithmetic by definition are due to carelessness and not necessarily due to shaky foundations. Sometimes when we do a long calculation it is possible to think one thing and write something else. 
1)Take time to read the questions to see what exactly you are asked to do so that you need not strike off your answer and start over again. 
2)Save some time for double checking your answers before finalising it.
3)Practice solving different types of problems and that will help you get used to various patterns.
4)When writing exam it is better to write once in a normal pace and correctly rather than write very fast, make mistakes and start over again.

Answer (score 0):

A common occurrence is to get toward the end and think, "ooops, that's obviously wrong!" Go back to somewhere around the halfway mark, and ask, "Did it make sense at that stage?" If it did, probably your mistake was in the second half, so look at the three-quarter point. It is like root-finding by repeated bisection.

Comment: And my old mathematics teacher said that when you are unsure about the sign, put down a big bold minus, and then think about it. You can ways change a minus to a plus.